# DocBook quick start

Tags: linux, pdf, authoring, docbook

I want to produce a `PDF` file out from a DocBook source on a Debian system. What should I do?

*Sorry for the n00b way of posting this, but it seems I'm unable to find anything around (compared to LaTeX). And onestly I'm very surprised about that.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docbooks are XML, and get transformed to output formats using xslt processing and css stylesheets.

There are some resources online: [DocBook xsl](http://www.sagehill.net/docbookxsl/) seems promising. This [docbook format page](http://www.docbook.org/specs/cs-docbook-docbook-4.2.html) also.

There seems to be a Debian package to help you called [dblatex](http://packages.debian.org/sid/dblatex). It seems to convert from docbook => latex => dvi => pdf under the hood, so be prepared to pull in a bunch of packages for it.

Sorry I can't help further; I use neither docbook format nor the Debian distribution.

Comment: Yeah, I assume `dblatex` is a good starting point, at least I'm able to produce some output now.